# Is my gas supply likely to travel through the floor or ceiling? [UK]

Tags: gas, uk

Our gas supply enters the property at the front and can be seen entering the wall cavity. The boiler is currently in the kitchen at the back of the property. To reach the kitchen is the gas pipe likely to be running within the solid ground floor of the house or travelling up the cavity and through the ceiling void between the ground and first floors? The house was built in the 1990s. Anyone know what was expected practice at the time? For clarity this is in the UK.

Comment: Gas pipe routed in a cavity is not allowed (only allowed to cross cavity from one side to the other) - does this reduce the possible routes?

Comment: Could the pipe cross the cavity but then still travel up behind the studwork of the plasterboard faced wall? Any idea if this rule was in place 25 years ago?

Comment: Where was it in the end out of interest?

Comment: Turns out it was running in the ceiling void between the ground and first floor. Builders took up the upstairs floor to access it. Apparently standard on properties of this type/age. Strikes me as a bit scary how easy it could be to puncture the pipe when hammering/cutting into the ceiling/floor. But then I can't think of many places you could site it that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can go below the ground floor, between the floors or through the roof.

All you have to do is find it.

I put one in and the gas copper pipe is in a 3" plastic tube actually buried in the new concrete floor.

My parents bungalow has the gas in the roof as the boiler is up there and the cooking stove in the kitch so the gas comes down behind the kitchen cabinets.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was running in the ceiling void between the ground and first floor. Builders took up the upstairs floor to access it. Apparently standard on properties of this type/age. The house was built by Beazer/Persimmon Homes in the 90s.